# How to add dropdown CSS class to menus with children in Drupal 7? (without modules)

Tags: php, drupal, drop-down-menu, drupal-7

How can I create a function to scan all menu items from Drupal 7 system and if there is a nested ul, add dropdown CSS classes to the nested ul and add a custom attribute to the parent li container? Im using [UIKIT](http://getuikit.com) which will automatically create the dropdowns.

Here's my current menu HTML output:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="first last expanded">
    <a title="" href="/node/add">Add content</a>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="first leaf">
            <a title="article" href="/node/add/article">Article</a></li>
         <li class="leaf">
            <a title="page" href="/node/add/page">Basic page</a></li>
  <li class="last leaf"><a title="blog" href="/node/add/blog">Blog entry</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here's what I need it to be:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="first last expanded" data-uk-dropdown>
    <a title="" href="/node/add">Add content</a>
      <ul class="menu uk-dropdown">
        <li class="first leaf">
            <a title="article" href="/node/add/article">Article</a></li>
         <li class="leaf">
            <a title="page" href="/node/add/page">Basic page</a></li>
  <li class="last leaf"><a title="blog" href="/node/add/blog">Blog entry</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Im looking for the simplest approach possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can crawl menu tree your self and write out menu HTML as you like. Used that and should be something like:

```
  $tree = menu_tree_all_data('menu_machine_name');
```

Also, if I remember well, if you do only that your active (current) menu item won't be marked any way, and for marking it you have to also call (after getting `$tree` variable) :

```
  menu_tree_add_active_path($tree);
```

But again, if I remember well, that function is only available if you install "Menu block" module...

Print out `$tree` variable after that and organize your code to crawl recursively menu tree you collected.